# Getting data from simple SELECT using twisted.enterprise.adbapi

Tags: mysql, twisted

I am able to do mySQL data insert using following,

```
from twisted.enterprise.adbapi import ConnectionPool
.
.
self.factory.pool.runOperation ('insert into table ....')
```

But, somehow unable to figure out how to do a simple select from an adbapi call to mySQL like following,

```
self.factory.pool.runOperation('SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = (%s)',customer)
```

How do I retrieve the id value from this partilcar call? I was working OK with plain python but somehow really fuzzed up with the twisted framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

`runOperation` isn't for *SELECT* statements.  It is for statements that do not produce rows, eg *INSERT* and *DELETE*.

Statements that produce rows are supported by `runQuery`.  For example:

```
pool = ...
d = pool.runQuery("SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = (%s)", (customer,))
def gotRows(rows):
    print 'The user id is', rows
def queryError(reason):
    print 'Problem with the query:', reason
d.addCallbacks(gotRows, queryError)
```

In this example, `d` is an instance of `Deferred`.  If you haven't encountered Deferreds before, you definitely want to read up about them: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html

Comment: Hi Jean-Paul - Thanks a mil! Still trying to get the grips of working around the twisted framework - I hope the async performance gains are worth the slight complexity.